# Buscar dados de 2 tabelas - PHP+CodeIgniter.

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, estou começando meus estudos em codeIgniter e me deparei com seguinte.

Tenho uma tabela de empregador e outra de vagas, a vaga possui id do empregador. Eu gostaria de mostrar os dados das 2 tabelas. Por exemplo: Eu digito algo e vai aparecer os dados da vaga e do empregador. Para aparecer os dados da vaga eu fiz:

Model:

```
function getVaga($campo_busca) {

$this->db
          ->select("*")
          ->from("dados_vaga")
          ->like('cargo',$campo_busca); 


    return  $qr = $this->db->get()->result();

}
```

Já no controller:

```
  public function teste(){

  $campo_busca = $this->input->post('teste');

  $data = array(
      "dados" => $this->Vaga_model->getVaga($campo_busca)
  );


  $this->load->view('busca', $data);
```

O id do empregador está nessa tabela dados_vaga para saber qual é o dono dessa vaga, agora não sei como faço para passar o mesmo como parametro para outra query.

Boa noite a todos, obrigado a quem responder, grande abraço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isso:

```
function getVaga($campo_busca) {

     $this->db
          ->select("*")
          ->from("dados_vaga")
          ->join("dados_empregador", "dados_empregador.id = dados_vaga.id_empregador")
          ->like('dados_vaga.cargo',$campo_busca); 

    return  $qr = $this->db->get()->result();

}
```

Obviamente substitua o "dados_empregador" e os campos de ID entre as 2 tabelas conforme a necessidade.

Mais informações sobre o JOIN no CI você encontra no link abaixo:
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Boa sorte!